# pytest how to pass request fixture through intermediary fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have (in pytest):

- `base` fixture that uses `request.param`
- `intermediary` fixture that uses the `base` fixture
- Test that uses the `intermediary` fixture, and I want to `parameterize` the `base` fixture

The below code sample will help explain:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def base(request) -> int:
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def intermediary(base: int) -> int:
    return base

# This does not work!  "In test_something: indirect fixture 'base' doesn't exist"
@pytest.mark.parametrize("intermediary", [1], indirect=["base"])
def test_something(intermediary: int) -> None:
    assert isinstance(intermediary, int)
```

**My question**: how can I populate `request` of the `base` fixture, from a test that uses only the `intermediary` fixture?

---

**Workaround**

Including the base fixture in the test signature works:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("base", [1], indirect=True)
def test_something_workaround(base: int, intermediary: int) -> None:
    assert isinstance(intermediary, int)
```

However, this is undesirable to me, because the test doesn't actually use `base`, only `intermediary`.

---

**Versions**

```
Python==3.8
pytest==6.2.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it almost this way, but you have to use "base" as the fixture name in `parametrize`:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def base(request) -> int:
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture
def intermediary(base: int) -> int:
    return base + 1


@pytest.mark.parametrize("base", [1], indirect=True)
def test_something(intermediary: int) -> None:
    assert intermediary == 2
```

E.g. you parametrize fixture `base`, but use the derived fixture, which than gets the result from `base`.